# Can you combine the Orbital Teleporter's ability with other Alien Tech cards?

Tags: alien-frontiers

Consider the following:

- I have an Orbital Teleporter and a Stasis Beam
- I roll 5,5,6
- I have 3 ore

I place the 6 at the Solar Array to claim 3 energy, then use the Orbital Teleporter to move the 6 to the Colony Constructor. I use the Stasis Beam to reduce it from a 6 to a 5, then place the other two fives and pay three ore to use the Colony Constructor to place a colony.

**Is this legal, or am I not allowed to alter a ship I'm moving with the Orbital Teleporter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, while there is no restriction on using different alien tech on the same ship, the rules for **Orbital Teleporter** specifically prevent a ship already placed from having its value changed when moved to another facility. **Stasis Beam** also doesn't work on placed ships. [Rules, page 14](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/56373/alien-frontiers-rules-pdf)

> **Orbital Teleporter** - Each turn you may pay two fuel to move one of your docked ships from one orbital facility to a different orbital facility. You may only move one of your ships with the Orbital Teleporter but the moved ship may be used at the new facility in conjunction with other as yet unplaced ships from your fleet. You may not reuse the ship at the same facility from which it was removed. **You may not change the value of the ship as it moves from one facility to the other.**
>
> **Stasis Beam** - Each turn you may pay one fuel to decrease the value of one **of your unplaced ships** by one point. You may discard a Stasis Beam to place the Isolation Field on a territory or, if the Isolation Field is already on a territory, move it to another territory. (Page 15)

[Card Reference (scans)](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/68154/alien-tech-card-player-reference-versions-2-2-and), and [card reference 2](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/71447/condensed-card-reference).

> **Orbital Teleporter** - Pay (E E) to reuse one of your ships at a different facility.
>
> **Stasis Beam** - Pay (E) to subtract one point **from one of your unplaced ship**.

Technically, you could achieve what it is you want by using one of your '5's on the Solar Collector, since it also gets you 3 energy. Then use the Stasis Beam to change the '6' to a '5', then use the remaining 2 energy to move the '5' from the Solar Collector with your remaining '5' and newly Stasis Beamed '5' onto the **Colony Constructor.**

Comment: I was afraid of that. It seemed clever when I did it in the game, and nobody called me on it, but now I can't do it again.

Comment: @PaulMarshall, as I indicated, you could have the same outcome of you played it slightly differently. No harm, no foul.

Comment: The example isn't perfect; if I'd been going for a triple-4, then I wouldn't have been able to get one free energy via Solar Collector + Orbital Teleporter. And I can't use both the Shipyard and the Raider's Outpost if I need to modify a die as I move it. (Say, I have 2355, and I want to use the Shipyard with the 55, then change a 5 to a 4, then use the Raider's Outpost with 234.)